# Dependency control for Python project

Tags: python, dependencies, version

I am working with python in my personal project, and when someone needs it, they be confused about version of python and its library.
So, is there something like Maven (java) for python version control.

Comment: did you use `virtualenv` ?

Comment: Note, this isn't what "version control" usually means. This is dependency management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to set required packages and versions you can use [requirements files](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html). [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) is used to create isolated environments for several projects. Say you use different dependency stacks or version for different projects, then you can use different virtual environments instead of changing your library versions. Of course you can use requirement files with virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper.

Version control is usually something like [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/) and is used to control versions of your code, not libraries/ dependencies, so I don't think you mean something like that?

Comment: Also you can specify your project's requirements in your `setup.py` file when doing a proper packaging for distribution, cf https://packaging.python.org/